# I want to add an image to home page of my flutter app.But am getting difficulties with its length and width

Tags: flutter

Because of that can't get a good view on different types of phones . I am trying to create an image using clip path library of flutter. Also i want to know whether there is any possibilities to add bootstrap and css to flutter?

Comment: if i have the css file with me, then it is possible to integrate that file in flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use Bootstrap or css in flutter.

To use a background image that fits the whole screen, you can use this :

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/images/yourimage.jpg"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: null /* add child content here */,
    ),
  );
}
```